# Why is my JButton Opening Multiple Instances Of The Same Window

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, inheritance, jframe

Hello why is my JButton opening multiple instances of the same JFrame? The LoginWn Opens first and has a button for a new user to enter their information that opens up on
another JFrame. The username and password then gets saved to a file. The NewUsrWn
extends the LoginWn to gain access to the static variables I've placed there for the
NewUsrWn class. The issue is probably because of the inheritance on the NewUserWn but I
want to know for sure first before changing everything. And if that is problem, is their
a way around this? Without having to remove the inheritance and making both classes
completely separate? (P.S I've left out some unnecessary code to get to main problem
areas).

```
package loggerPack;



public class CreatesJFrameWithCompnents {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
LoginWn loginWn = new NewUsrWn( );
    
        }
   }
```

---

```
package loggerPack;

public class LoginWn implements ActionListener, KeyListener {  

   JButton loginBtn = new JButton( );
   JButton optBtn = new JButton( );
   JButton exitBtn = new JButton( );
   JTextField usrNmFld = new JTextField( );
   JPasswordField pswdFld = new JPasswordField( );
   JPanel panel1 = new JPanel( );
 
      
         public LoginWn( ) {
          frame.setBounds(100, 100, 727, 482);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          //Set Listener for Window
          JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane( ); 
          GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane( ));
          frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter( ) {
              public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode( );
                
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                     try {
                        sfx1.soundClip = ("C:\\Users\\Etienne Shelton\\Desktop\\Confirmation Sound.wav");
                        sfx1.iniateSfx( ); 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Audio Clip Failed To Start!!");
                      }
                    }
              }
              });
          frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter( ) {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
              exitForm( );
                    }
                });
            
            layeredPane = new JLayeredPane( );
                groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane( ));
                groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                    groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(layeredPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 744, 
                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                );
                groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                    groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(layeredPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 463, 
           GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                );

    
        
           loginBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Etienne Shelton\\Desktop\\Java IDE 
           Files\\Glossy Blue JButton.png"));
           loginBtn.setFocusable(false);
           loginBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener( ) {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
               
                String retrvdUsrNm;
        String retrvdPswd;
        retrvdUsrNm = usrNmFld.getText( );
        retrvdPswd  = pswdFld.getText( );
        
                try {
                BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("userDataFile.txt"));
                inputFile.readLine( );
                for (int i = 0; i < fileEntries.length; i++)  {
                        if (retrvdUsrNm.equals(cnfrmdUsrNm) && retrvdPswd.equals(cnfrmdPswd)) {
                            loginGd = true;
                            sfx1.soundClip = ("C:\\Users\\Etienne Shelton\\Desktop\\Confirmation Sound.wav");
                            sfx1.iniateSfx( ); 
                            new SelectionWn( );
                        }
                            else if (!retrvdUsrNm.equals(cnfrmdUsrNm) && 
                 !retrvdPswd.equals(cnfrmdPswd)) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, 
                                "You Must Enter The Correct Username and Password!");                                   
                            }
                        }
                        inputFile.close( );          
        }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.print("Error");
          }
```

---

```
package loggerPack;



   public class NewUsrWn extends LoginWn implements TestLbl {
    //Instances
    public JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
    public JPanel panel = new JPanel( );
    public static JButton setBtn = new JButton( );
    public static JTextField usrTxtFld = new JTextField( );
    public static JPasswordField pswdTxtFld = new JPasswordField( );

     //GUI Components
     public NewUsrWn( ) {
            
            JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane( );
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 512, 499);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane( ));
            groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(layeredPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 751, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
            groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(layeredPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 461, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            
            
            usrTxtFld.setBounds(152, 109, 184, 23);
            usrTxtFld.setColumns(10);
            usrTxtFld.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            usrTxtFld.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            layeredPane.setLayer(usrTxtFld, 3);
            layeredPane.add(usrTxtFld);
            
            lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Etienne Shelton\\Desktop\\Java IDE Files\\Galaxy Background 1 Resized.jpg"));
            lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 496, 461);
            layeredPane.add(lblNewLabel);
            
            panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            panel.setBounds(107, 76, 279, 374);
            layeredPane.setLayer(panel, 2);
            layeredPane.add(panel);
            
            setBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Etienne Shelton\\Desktop\\Java IDE Files\\Glossy Blue JButton.png"));
            setBtn.setBounds(193, 222, 89, 23);
            setBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener( ) {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setBtn.requestFocus( );
                    setBtnActionPerformed(e);
                  
                }
            });
            layeredPane.setLayer(setBtn, 3);
            layeredPane.add(setBtn);
            
            //Set Letters
            setLtrs.setBounds(223, 222, 89, 23);
            layeredPane.setLayer(setLtrs, 4);
            layeredPane.add(setLtrs);
            
            
            
            
            pswdTxtFld.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            pswdTxtFld.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            pswdTxtFld.setColumns(10);
            pswdTxtFld.setBounds(152, 188, 184, 23);
            pswdTxtFld.addActionListener(new ActionListener( ) {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            pswdTxtFld.requestFocus(  );    
                }
            });
            layeredPane.setLayer(pswdTxtFld, 3);
            layeredPane.add(pswdTxtFld);
            
            
            //Back Btn
            bckBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Etienne Shelton\\Desktop\\Java IDE Files\\Glossy Blue JButton.png"));
            bckBtn.setBounds(193, 256, 89, 23);
            bckBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener( ) {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    frame.dispose( );
                }
            });
            layeredPane.setLayer(bckBtn, 3);
            layeredPane.add(bckBtn);
            
            frame.getContentPane( ).setLayout(groupLayout);
       }

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CreatesJFrameWithComponents class, you are creating a NewUsrWn object but storing it in a LoginWn reference:

LoginWn loginWn = new NewUsrWn();

Since NewUsrWn extends LoginWn, when you create a NewUsrWn, it will also invoke the constructor of LoginWn. This could be the reason why you're seeing multiple instances of the same JFrame.

Remove the inheritance of NewUsrWn from LoginWn. Instead, create separate instances for each window and handle their components independently. Inheritance should be used when there is a clear "is-a" relationship between classes, and in this case, it seems like both classes represent different windows with different functionalities.

public class CreatesJFrameWithComponents {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginWn loginWindow = new LoginWn();
}
```

}

public class LoginWn {

```
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login Window");
private JButton loginBtn = new JButton("Login");

public LoginWn() {
    // Initialize components and add them to the frame
    frame.add(loginBtn);
    // Set frame properties and make it visible
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

// Other methods and event listeners for the login window
```

}

public class NewUsrWn {

```
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("New User Window");
private JButton setBtn = new JButton("Set");
private JTextField usrTxtFld = new JTextField();

public NewUsrWn() {
    // Initialize components and add them to the frame
    frame.add(setBtn);
    frame.add(usrTxtFld);
    // Set frame properties and make it visible
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

// Other methods and event listeners for the new user window
```

}